# JavaScript While Loop issue

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```
function draw() {
  background(51);
  balloon.show();
  balloon.update();
  score.time();
  var state = 0;

  if (frameCount % 100 == 0) {
    blocks.push(new Blocks());

  }

  while (state != 1) {
    for (var i = blocks.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        blocks[i].show();
        blocks[i].update();

        if (blocks[i].offscreen()) {
           blocks.splice(i, 1);
        }

        if (blocks[i].hits(balloon)) {
            blocks = null
            console.log("hitted");
            state = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

So basically I just want the blocks array to stop drawing themselves on the screen once the "balloon" object hits one of them. I get no error after running it, and I get the text written on the console, so the collision is working as intended. Any ideas why the loop doesn't stop?

Comment: probably `if (blocks[i].hits(balloon))` never positive

Comment: You'll have to break from the `for` loop. Add a `break` statement after the `this.state = 1` statement.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly he says the text is shown in the console

Comment: `blocks.speed = 0;` should probably be `blocks[i].speed = 0;`

Comment: Try putting 'break;' on the line after 'this.state = 1';  There are two loops, the while loop and the for loop.  It's not going to break out of the for loop until it reaches the end of the blocks.  Might not fix it, but can't hurt.  you want to break out of that loop there anyways

Comment: @chairmanmow The issue is still there, sadly

Comment: The meaning of `this` can be tricky in javascript, depending on what the context is where it's being used.  Since we are seeing so little of your code it's difficult to deliberate on its use in your posted code ... are you _sure_ you want `this.state = 0;` and not just `var state = 0;` here? Following your code through it looks like it _should_ terminate when state is set to 1 (just wasting some iterations of the `for` loop as chairmanmow points out)

Comment: Updated the post with the whole function. I've tried all sort of things but it keeps on an infinite loop